# React: Click text, dynamically append form and use it to rename text

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to know how to write code that does the following using React.js
I sketched a JQuery example to demo what I want:

http://jsfiddle.net/k3j7u6zv/

```
let form = " <form class='update-name'> <input type='text' class='room-new-name'> <input type='submit'> </form>"

$(".room-name").on("click",function(){
     let parent = $(this).parent()
     parent.append(form)
})


$(".room").on("submit",function(event){
    event.preventDefault()


     let newName = $(".room-new-name").val()
     $(".room-name").text(newName)
     $(".room > .update-name").remove()

})
```

React code....(not exactly sure how to even think about this using react)

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      rooms:[{name:"coffee talk"},{name:"cooking"},{name:"skateboarding"},{name:"coding"}]

    }

  }

  changeName(){
    // ?
  }

  render() {

      let roomList = this.state.rooms.map((val,index)=>{
                       return <li key={index}>{val.name}</li> 
      })

    return (
         <div>
            <ul>
              {roomList}
            </ul>  
         </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
      <App/>
    </div>,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Comment: do you want to append a newly generated form each time or just hide/show ONE form on click?

Comment: I posted my own answer below. One form see fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured this out but I am not sure if this is "best practice" or close to it.

http://jsfiddle.net/od6ces0a/1/

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      rooms:[{name:"coffee talk"},{name:"cooking"},{name:"skateboarding"},{name:"coding"}],
      roomCSS:{display:"none"},
      selectedRoomIndex:undefined,
      tempName:"",

    }

  }

  setRoomIndex=(roomID)=>{
    console.log(roomID);
     this.setState({
          selectedRoomIndex:roomID,
          roomCSS:{display:"block"}
     })
  }


  handleChange=(event)=> {
    this.setState({tempName: event.target.value});
  }


  setNewRoomName=(event)=>{
    event.preventDefault()

    let updatedRoomList = this.state.rooms.map((val,index)=>{
         if(index === this.state.selectedRoomIndex){
           val.name = this.state.tempName;
           return val
         }else{
           return val
         }
    })


    this.setState({
        rooms:updatedRoomList,
        roomCSS:{display:"none"},
        tempName:""
    })
  }


  render() {


      let roomList = this.state.rooms.map((val,index)=>{
                       return <li onClick = {()=>this.setRoomIndex(index)} key={index}>
                                 <span>{val.name}</span>
                               </li> 
      });

    return (
         <div>
            <ul>
               <form onSubmit={this.setNewRoomName} className="change-room-name" style={this.state.roomCSS}> 
                 <input type="text" onChange = {this. handleChange} value={this.state.tempName}/> 
                 <input type="submit"/>
               </form>
               {roomList}
            </ul>  
         </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
      <App/>
    </div>,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Comment: React best practice is to hide elements by not rendering them instead of rendering them with ```display: none;```. Instead of changing the css in state, change a boolean value. Inside render you can use ```{this.state.roomHidden ? (<div />) : (<form> ... </form>)}```. This way the hidden element is not rendered until it is needed. Additionally, you could have a similar hidden form for each element in a list without taking a performance hit, unlike the css approach.